# Correct wall anchor to use - Drywall + hard foam on concrete blocks

Tags: walls, drywall-anchor

I'm trying to hang shelves on a basement wall in a house built in the mid 1980s.

The walls have no studs (at least that I can find). They are drywall on top of 2" hard foam insulation, which is attached directly to the concrete block wall.

Normally I use the white spiral wall anchors to hang up things that are up to 50 pounds or so, but these shelves will have to hold up to 200 pounds of stuff and I don't want to risk the shelves pulling off of the wall.

Any ideas? I do not have a hammer drill, so getting anything into the concrete block is very difficult. Is renting a drill and using some blue concrete screws my best choice?

Comment: It is possible there are no studs, but I doubt it.  200 pounds of stuff is probably expensive to replace and hurts bad when it falls on you.  A nice bookcase there might be an idea, if no studs found.

Comment: If there are studs, I can't find them. Dragged a studfinder across the whole wall at various heights with nothing detected.

Comment: What about something like the Closetmaid Shelve Track attached to the header? It's definitely there on top of the cinder blocks.

Comment: Also, bookshelf is not an option, as there is a desk below.

Comment: A solid header or studs would both be good places to anchor, a lot better than drywall only for that weight.  2 1/2 inches in spongy material is a bit much for screws to not bend holding that weight.

Comment: If you’re really loading heavily, the wood at the top of the wall may or may not be sufficiently attached to hang a closetmaid-style system. Strongly suggest anchoring into the block wall.